# Whats a word/phrase for stuck between two worlds?

Tags: meaning

STuck bewtween two different worlds, like 2 differenct cultures

Answer (score 1):

'to fall between two stools', if you are truly in neither culture:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-between-two-stools

OR Maybe

'a foot in both camps', if you are in both but they are normally mutually exclusive:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-foot-in-both-camps?q=a+foot+in+both+camps

Answer (score 1):

> "limbo - an intermediate state or condition."

or

> "purgatory - (in Roman Catholic doctrine) a place or state of
>   suffering inhabited by the souls of sinners who are expiating their
>   sins before going to heaven."

This is often used, perhaps erroneously, to being stuck between two worlds (heaven and earth), though without the suffering and expiating aspect.